# What factors contribute to the loss of kinetic energy in a partially inelastic collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics, momentum, collision

In partially inelastic collision, the objects involved in the collisions do not stick, but some kinetic energy is still lost. Friction, sound and heat are some ways the kinetic energy can be lost through partial inelastic collisions. Suppose there are two blocks on a frictionless surface. These blocks undergo partially inelastic collision. My question is: What factors will determine or contribute to the amount of kinetic energy lost during collision of these two bodies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: What factors will determine or contribute to the
> amount of kinetic energy lost during collision of these two bodies?

I believe the primary factor is the degree to which material deformation results in internal dissipative (heat producing) forces. Some kinetic energy is lost in the form of sound (unless the objects collide in a vacuum) due to the vibrations resulting from friction.

The elastic behavior in a collision can be modeled as an ideal spring, Fig 1. A  collision between objects exhibiting perfectly elastic behavior involves no loss of kinetic energy (perfectly elastic collisions) as a result of any deformation. The electrical analog is an ideal capacitor that can store and release electrical energy without any losses.

The complete inelastic behavior may be modeled as the viscous behavior of an ideal dashpot, Fig 2 below. The electrical analog is a resistor. Any deformation resulting from collisions is permanent and associated with a loss of kinetic energy (actually, conversion of macroscopic kinetic energy to internal microscopic kinetic energy increasing temperature and producing heat). The result is the maximum amount of kinetic energy loss, consistent with conservation of momentum. Two objects that stick together upon impact is an example.

In between these extremes you have viscoelastic behavior, a combination of elastic and viscous behavior. Here the collisions are partially inelastic. Figures 3 through 6 are examples of mechanical models of such behavior. They differ to represent various possible time-dependent behaviors associated with creep, recovery, and relaxation.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is "How to quantify the energy lost during an inelastic collision?"

So to begin with, if you consider a 2 body system, during collision all the forces are internal. So you can conserve the momentum.

And depending on the nature of the surfaces on which collision occurs, each material has its unique "Coefficient of restitution".

Simply saying, it is ratio between relative velocities before collison to the relative velocities after collision (The magnitude only in taken). This is for a one dimensional collision.

For 2-D collisions you take the components normal to the surface of collision.

I suggest you learn more about it, as several sources are available on google.

From this and momentum conservation, you can easily calculate the final velocities and hence find the difference in kinetic energy which is lost as heat, sound etc

Answer (score 2):

Kinetic energy losses will be determined by a material property known as the *coefficient of restitution*. This number is equal to 1 for a perfectly elastic material having no *internal friction* losses which dissipate the kinetic energy, and is less than 1 for materials which are dissipative.

The classic example of a dissipative material is one exhibiting *viscoelasticity*, where upon being stressed it stores some elastic energy while also dissipating some energy as heat. Low-grade rubber acts this way.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the two objects are ball bearing assemblies, with the inner race wider than the rest, so that only that inner races touch the frictionless surface.

If they have only translational movement before the collision, they start to spin after it (unless their path is perfectly radial).

So part of the energy is rotational after the collision.

The principle of inelastic collisions is always the same: part of the translational energy transforms in some form of internal energy.